# to populate one dropdown on selectedindexchanged of another inside gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

I have gridview with two dropdowns in a row say country and state,on change of country dropdown i want to populate the state dropdown when the grid is in edit state.
I got both the dropdowns in RowEditing event of grid,also selectedindexchanged event is attached to first dropdown of grid.The problem is how to get second dropdown i.e. state dropdown in selectedindexchange event of country dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `RowEditing` event occurs before dropdown selection changed event, you can store reference to current `Row` in you application. Then get this row in dropdown changed event.

Comment: that won't work as dropdown index change will cause a postback and reference gets lost

Comment: ok, you should specify `ASP.NET WebForms` tag in your question. Does you gridview provide `SelectedRow` property? Is it accessible on postback? Or maybe `EditingRow` property.

Comment: I always get SelectedRow as null...am also not much aware about this property

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl1 = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl1.NamingContainer;
        if (row != null)
        {
            DropDownList ddl2 = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList3");
            {
                //call the method for binding the second DDL based on the selected item on the first DDL
                DataTable dt = BindDropDownList(ddl1.SelectedItem.Text);
                ddl2.DataTextField = "Field1";
                ddl2.DataValueField = "Field2";
                ddl2.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```